# Why won't this Expect Exception Junit Test Work?

Tags: java, testing, junit, expected-exception

This is my test so far:

```
@Test(expected = FileNotFoundException.class)
public void testExpectedException() {
    UserDataObject u = new UserDataObject("rob123", "Smith", "Robert", "Danny", 1);
    FlatFileStorage ffstorage = new FlatFileStorage();
    ffstorage.verifyUser(u, "dsfsdfsfdsdf.txt");
```

However, the test seems to fail! Even though when I run it, the error message actually gets printed out from the method on the console too, like this

```
dsfsdfsfdsdf.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Am I missing something really obvious here?

EDIT** Here is the method I'm actually testing

```
public void verifyUser(UserDataObject u, String filename) {

    String eachline = "";
    String uname = u.getUsername();
    Scanner sc;


    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((eachline = br.readLine())!=null) 
            {
                if(eachline.indexOf("Username: " + uname)!=-1)
                {
                    int lineStart = eachline.indexOf("Username: " + uname);
                    int lineEnd = eachline.indexOf("end" + uname + ";");
                    int unameLength = uname.length();

                    String lineStatus = eachline.substring(lineStart, lineEnd + 4 + unameLength);
                    //System.out.println(lineStatus);

                    String newLineStatus = lineStatus.replace("VerifyStatus: 0", "VerifyStatus: 1");

                    sb.append(newLineStatus+"\n");

                }else{
                    sb.append(eachline+"\n");
                }
            } 
            br.close();
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filename)));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
            out.print(sb.toString());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Could not find database/storage.");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("There has been an error: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }   

 }
```

Comment: Do you have the exception stack trace?

Comment: Make sure the exception is actually `FileNotFoundException` as an `IOException` can display that same message.

Comment: The stacktrace prints out
"java.io.FileNotFoundException: dsfsdfsfdsdf.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)"

Comment: And I tried re-running the test with IOException instead of FileNotFoundException - still fails!

Comment: @oOTesterOo Try specifying full path of exception class.

Comment: Cheers - just tried that, but it still failed. I'll put my actual method in an edit in my post. Maybe some hints in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is failing because you are expecting the FileNotFoundException, but it not actualy thrown from a method. Why? Because of try/catch wrapper, that swallows the exception, only printing the stack trace to the output.

Change the catch block to

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Could not find database/storage.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
            throw e;
            }
```

and test will pass

Comment: Usually you want to log or throw. Not both. If the exception is thrown then the caller will log it if needed.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your `verifyUser(UserDataObject u, String filename)` method catches both exceptions `FileNotFoundException` and `IOException` and hence it is not propagated to your test method.